# Phone Verification using Firebase without authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the below code to verify the mobile number provided by a already logged in user. This is being done through Firebase Phone Authentication with the final step for signing into firebase with received credential not being carried out. But no SMS is being sent/received... and the app keeps crashing?

```
 initView()
    startVerfiy()

    verifyOTPBtn.setOnClickListener {
        // try to enter the code by yourself to handle the case
        // if user enter another sim card used in another phone ...
        var code = enterOTPNo.text
        Log.e("code is --- ", code.toString())
        if (code != null && !code.isEmpty() && mVerificationId != null && !mVerificationId!!.isEmpty()) {

            showProgressDialog(this, "please wait...", false)

            val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId!!, code.toString())
            showMessagesActivity()
//                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }
    }

    //Resend OTP
    resendOTP.setOnClickListener {
        if (mResendToken != null && !isTimerActive) {
            resendVerificationCode(phoneNumber.toString(), mResendToken)
            showTimer(60000)
            showProgressDialog(this, "Sending a verification code", false)
        } else {
            toast("Sorry, You Can't request new code now, Please wait ...")
        }
    }

    //Reset no option
//        wrong_tv.setOnClickListener {

//            showLoginActivity()
//        }

}

private fun resendVerificationCode(
    phoneNumber: String,
    token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?
) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
        60, // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
        this, // Activity (for callback binding)
        callbacks, // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        token
    ) // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}

private fun initView() {
    // init vars from bundle
    phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber")

    // init fire base verfiyPhone number callback
    callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(verificationId: String) {
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
            }
            notifyUserAndRetry("Time Out :( failed.Retry again!")
        }

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            Log.e("onVerificationCompleted", "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
            }

            val smsMessageSent: String = credential.smsCode.toString()
            Log.e("the message is ----- ", smsMessageSent)
            if (smsMessageSent != null){
                enterOTPNo.setText(smsMessageSent)
            }

            //Saving access setting in Shared Preferences
            val preferences = getSharedPreferences("MessagesAccess", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString("noVerified","1")
            editor.apply()
            //Display Messages Activity
            showMessagesActivity()
//                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.e("+++2", "onVerificationFailed", e)

            if (progressDialog != null) {
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
            }

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Log.e("Exception:", "FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException", e)
                Log.e("=========:", "FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException " + e.message)


            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Log.e("Exception:", "FirebaseTooManyRequestsException", e)
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
            notifyUserAndRetry("Your Phone Number might be wrong or connection error.Retry again!")

        }

//            override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String?, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
//                //for low level version which doesn't do auto verification save the verification code and the token
//
//                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
//                timeRemaining.visibility = View.GONE
//                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
//                Log.e("onCodeSent===", "onCodeSent:$verificationId")
//
//                mVerificationId = verificationId
//                mResendToken = token
//
//            }
    }
}

private fun startVerfiy() {

    Log.e("User Phone Number ===  ", phoneNumber!!)

    if (phoneNumber != null && !phoneNumber!!.isEmpty()) {
        startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber!!)
        showTimer(60000)
        showProgressDialog(this, "Sending a verification code", false)
    } else {
        toast("Please enter a valid number to continue!")
    }
}

//    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
//        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
//        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
//            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
//                if (task.isSuccessful) {
//
//                    if (progressDialog != null) {
//                        dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
//                    }
//
//                    val user = task.result.user
//                    Log.e("Sign in with phone auth", "Success $user")
//                    showMessagesActivity()
//                } else {
//
//                    if (progressDialog != null) {
//                        dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog)
//                    }
//
//                    notifyUserAndRetry("Your Phone Number Verification is failed.Retry again!")
//                }
//            }
//    }

// This method will send a code to a given phone number as an SMS
private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,      // Phone number to verify
        60,               // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
        this,            // Activity (for callback binding)
        callbacks
    ) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}

private fun notifyUserAndRetry(message: String) {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { arg0, arg1 -> showLoginActivity() })

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> showLoginActivity() })

    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
}

// helpers methods :)
private fun toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun showTimer(milliesInFuture: Long) {
    isTimerActive = true
    mCounterDown = object : CountDownTimer(milliesInFuture, 1000) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            timeLeft = millisUntilFinished
            timeRemaining.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            timeRemaining.text = "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000


            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            timeRemaining.visibility = View.GONE
            isTimerActive = false
        }

    }.start()
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putLong("timeLeft", timeLeft)
    outState.putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
}

private fun showProgressDialog(
    mActivity: Context,
    message: String,
    isCancelable: Boolean
): ProgressDialog {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(mActivity)
    progressDialog!!.show()
    progressDialog!!.setCancelable(isCancelable)
    progressDialog!!.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    progressDialog!!.setMessage(message)
    return progressDialog as ProgressDialog
}

private fun dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog: ProgressDialog?) {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing) {
        progressDialog.dismiss()
    }
}

private fun showLoginActivity() {
    startActivity(
        Intent(this, LoginPhoneScreen::class.java)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    )
}

private fun showMessagesActivity() {

    //first save phone number to data base and then call TODO worker to sync phone numbers for contacts

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
    phoneRefUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("PhoneDirectory").child(phoneNumber!!)

    //to save message on Firebase - Users Node
    val usersHashMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    usersHashMap["verPhone"] = phoneNumber

    val phoneDirectoryHashMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
    phoneDirectoryHashMap["userId"] = firebaseUser!!.uid

    //to save message on Firebase - Users Phone Directory Node
    phoneRefUsers!!.updateChildren(phoneDirectoryHashMap).addOnCompleteListener {
        refUsers!!.updateChildren(usersHashMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent = Intent(this, Messages::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
    }

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    finish()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    if (mCounterDown != null) {
        mCounterDown!!.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the crash logcat.

Comment: Application just times out, no error.... when i first submit no it dosent go to SafetyNet but goes to firebase to check if its a bot and then it just hangs and crashes no error...